# How to get OCSP responses through openssl apis in cms signed data

Tags: c++, openssl, ocsp

I've been developing some logic to get certificates and its revocation list in cms signed data.  The format of certificates is X509v3 and revocation list is OCSP responses.

According to [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652): *"Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) Responses can be supported using the OtherRevocationInfoFormat."*

So I `#include <openssl/cms.h>` and get x509v3 certificates through:

```
STACK_OF(X509) *CMS_get1_certs(CMS_ContentInfo *cms);
```

*(See: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/CMS_get1_certs.html)*

But, I do not know how to get OCSP responses via openssl in C++.  There is only:

```
STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *CMS_get1_crls(CMS_ContentInfo *cms);
```

But that gets a revocation info list as crls, not OCSP response.

I found that in the [`cms_lcl.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/cms/cms_lcl.h), revocation info is included in `CMS_RevocationInfoChoice` as an union type:

```
struct CMS_RevocationInfoChoice_st {
    int type;
    union {
        X509_CRL *crl;
        CMS_OtherRevocationInfoFormat *other;
    } d;
};
```

But, I can't find the way to get it.  Do I need to import other libraries?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please look at the [MarkDown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to understand how to link and format your posts.  I [made some edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52355286/revisions) to improve the readability of your question, but you can edit further for clarity and to add more information.

Comment: As you can see, `CMS_RevocationInfoChoice_st` contains union. Exact type of the union is determined by a `type` field. For example, if `type == 0`, then structure contains pointer to CRL, if `type == 1`, then structure contains other revocation type. And it depends on CMS content. If it includes CRL (note that revocation structure is optional), it includes CRL, you cannot access OCSP response when it is not presented in CMS.

Comment: @HostileFork Hello thank you for clear guide. I'll refer it.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you for your help. But, Does C++ openssl provide apis to get OCSP responses?? I do not know how to get it. In contrast, openssl provide api to get crls included in CMS directly, through this api. `STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *CMS_get1_crls(CMS_ContentInfo *cms);`